# Cocoa WebView get page number for printing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing, webview

I want to do something rather straight forward:
I have a WebView with content I'd like to print. I'd like to add a custom footer including a page number.

I just can't figure out how to get the scroll position of the view!

Here's what I've tried:

```
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
[printInfo setTopMargin:30];
[printInfo setBottomMargin:30];
[printInfo setLeftMargin:30];
[printInfo setRightMargin:30];
[printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:YES];
[printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];
[printInfo setOrientation:NSPaperOrientationPortrait];
[printInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];

NSMutableDictionary* printSettings = printInfo.printSettings;
printSettings[NSPrintHeaderAndFooter] = @(YES);

self.printWebView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 800.0f, 11.0f)];
self.printWebView.UIDelegate = self;
[self.printWebView setShouldUpdateWhileOffscreen:YES];
```

And this function is used to open the print panel:

```
- (IBAction)onPrintButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [[[[self.printWebView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] print:self];
}
```

When the print panel opens, these two delegate methods are called:

```
- (float)webViewFooterHeight:(WebView *)sender
{
    return 50.0f;
}

- (void) webView:(WebView *)sender drawFooterInRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);

    NSScrollView* view = sender.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.enclosingScrollView;

    NSLog(@"Rect: %@, %@, %@", NSStringFromRect(sender.mainFrame.frameView.frame),
      NSStringFromRect(sender.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.frame),
      NSStringFromRect(view.documentVisibleRect));
}
```

None of the printed frames changes when the page in the print preview changes. The delegates get called, but the frames are always the same.

How would I determine the page number?

Comment: Implement the scrollview delegate methods and listen for scrollViewDidScroll method which gets hit when you scroll the webView.

Comment: Forgot to add the "OS X" badge. There is no such delegate on OS X.

Comment: Printing doesn't scroll. Printing prints the total view and paginates if wanted and needed. Maybe `[NSPrintOperation currentOperation].currentPage` gives you the page number.

Comment: @Willeke  Thanks! That's what I found out in the meantime as well.